# Kubernetes Secret File from PFX without kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

i try to generate a Kubernetes Secret file witch include a PFX Certificate.
I want to create a yaml file with mutliple PFX files in there.
But i don´t finde a solution to base64 encode the PFX files so that they are working in yaml.
can someone help in this case?
kind regards
Matze

Getting a Base64 string for PFX files witch are working in Kubernetes Secret YAML

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the base64 command line tool or even an online encoder.
Create the Secret YAML and include the string.

For example run

```
base64 -w0 demo.ext
```

Comment: I wouldn't use an online encoder for any prod system -- you don't know if they can be trusted or not. Using the base64 tool, as recommended here, is a far better solution.